# How can I verify that a Steam key is legit?

Tags: unity, steam

I am developing a game that has online multiplayer. It will be available on Steam.

However, I do not want to use Steam authentication to use the online capabilities. I will use my own account system, so you must register with your email and password.

Which brings me to the next problem: how can I verify if this newly created account is a legit owner of the game in Steam? I can ask the player to provide their license key, but how could I verify that this key is valid? Does the Steam web API have a way to check if a key is valid, regardless of having been used to redeem the product or not?

Comment: Steam does not really give out licence keys, you could provide your own along with any purchases of your game though. (not sure how this would work out)

Comment: Why are you using your own type of account? What benefit is there from not using steamworks?

Comment: People already hate having to create Accounts for various online services (Origin, UPlay, Rockstar Social Club etc.). Why create a new one, which players will also hate?

Comment: Why not first authenticate via Steam (which is completely silent from the user's perspective) and when that was successful authenticate again using your own account management system?

Comment: @benh Because it is an MMO that connects with mobile players too (iOS, Android, etc). Surely it is not unheard of that an MMO has their own authentication system? Especially when they need to connect with mobile players too.

Comment: @LukeG Because it is an MMO that connects with mobile players too (iOS, Android, etc).

Comment: @Oxide this isn't justification for an accounts system on PC, the user should log in using steam normally on PC, and using your propriety system on mobile, you can have a token to link the steam account to the propriety account. It may be even easier to use the phone's inbuilt login system (google play services) and do the same thing with a shared token  to link the accounts. Forcing players to create a new account is a barrier to entry and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @benh I don't want to try to harmonize Steam, Google Play and Game Center when I already have an accounts system in place. I don't see the point in trying to make three services work together when I can just change a flag in my customer's account after verifying their purchase - something that I've *already* achieved in Android and iOS and now I'm just missing Steam. People may or may not hate having an account, but that has never killed a product ever. You may dislike it, but it works and helps keep things centralized and simple. Asking people to register is the last thing to kill my game.

Comment: @benh And it's not like the game will ask them to login every time they want to play, either. Just like Battlenet does (or any browser game, really), you can remain logged in indefinitely and just launch the game.